# Why webpack breaks when reading package.json?

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to execute webpack for my app but it fails when trying to bundle `package.json`.

```
  System:
    OS: Linux 5.15 Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)
    CPU: (16) x64 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-11950H @ 2.60GHz
    Memory: 18.65 GB / 31.05 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.15.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.23.0-20220130.1630 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.5.5 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 116.0.5845.110
  Packages:
    babel-loader: ^9.1.3 => 9.1.3 
    css-loader: ^6.8.1 => 6.8.1 
    webpack: ^5.88.2 => 5.88.2 
    webpack-cli: ^5.1.4 => 5.1.4
```

```
npx webpack
assets by status 13.6 MiB [cached] 2 assets
orphan modules 17.5 MiB [orphan] 3221 modules
runtime modules 8.64 KiB 14 modules
built modules 19.1 MiB [built]
  modules by path ./node_modules/ 19.1 MiB 492 modules
  asset modules 2.66 KiB
    data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns=%27.. 324 bytes [built] [code generated]
    data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns=%27.. 216 bytes [built] [code generated]
    data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns=%27.. 390 bytes [built] [code generated]
    data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns=%27.. 261 bytes [built] [code generated]
    data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns=%27.. 193 bytes [built] [code generated]
    data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns=%27.. 191 bytes [built] [code generated]
    + 4 modules
  ./target/index.js 823 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js 6.67 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./util.inspect (ignored) 15 bytes [built] [code generated]

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value.
Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

ERROR in ./node_modules/axios/package.json 2:8
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| {
>   "name": "axios",
|   "version": "0.21.4",
|   "description": "Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js",
 @ ./node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/validator.js 3:10-41
 @ ./node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js 8:16-47
 @ ./node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js 5:12-35
 @ ./node_modules/axios/index.js 1:0-39
 @ ./node_modules/l/dist/ui.esm.js 74:0-26 20400:2-12 23432:9-19
 @ ./target/index.js

webpack 5.88.2 compiled with 1 error and 1 warning in 45466 ms
```

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./target/index.js", // Entry point for your application
  output: {
    filename: "libs.js", // Output bundle file name
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/js"), // Output directory
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".mjs"], // Allow importing both .js and .mjs files without specifying the extension
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.json$/, type: "json" },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        type: "javascript/auto", // Treat .mjs files as JavaScript modules
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Am I missing some required configuration?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible code to reproduce this issue?